# Set Required to a custom Angular2 dropdown component

Tags: angular, required, form-fields

I have a form that has few input fields and a custom dropdown. The question is: Can I set my-custom-dropdown component to be required?

My form looks something like this:

```
<form name="myform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myform="ngForm">
    <!-- other fields omitted for brevity -->
    <my-custom-dropdown name="someValue" #someValue="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.someValue"></my-custom-dropdown>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My dropdown component is basically a custom component that looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <label>
        Set some value
    </label>
    <p class="form-control-static">{{model.name}}</p>
    <ul>
        <my-custom-dropdown-item *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index" [(value)]="model" [option]="option"></my-custom-dropdown-item>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And finally I have items of a dropdown like this:

```
<li>
    <!-- some structural and styling stuff omitted for brevity -->
    {{option.name}}
</li>
```

I'm using the latest version of Angular2. I did not include Typescript files but long story short, my-custom-dropdown component implements ControlValueAccessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is a simple directive that I can apply to a dropdown component:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

//validation function
function validateDropdownFactory(): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {
        let isValid = c.value !== null;

        if (isValid) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return {
                dropdownRequired: {
                    valid: false
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[dropdownRequired][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DropdownRequired, multi: true }
    ]
})

export class DropdownRequired implements Validator {
    validator: ValidatorFn;

    constructor() {
        this.validator = validateDropdownFactory();
    }

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }
}
```

And then I applied it like this:

```
<my-custom-dropdown name="someValue" #someValue="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.someValue" dropdownRequired></my-custom-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, your component need to implement ControlValueAccessor. Some good explanation for [this topic](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel). 
It seems like formControl have dependece from NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, if is not please anyone to provide some diffrent solution.
To make component requried:

1) In selector tag, where is used component insert formControlName directive and ngModel

```
<drop-down [items]="itemsOfQuestionType" [label]="questionTypeLabel" (change)="onChooseQuestionType($event)" formControlName="questionTypeDropDown" [(ngModel)]="selectedQuestionTypeId"></drop-down>
```

2) Somwhere in your code need to define validation rules.

```
complexForm : FormGroup;
formBuilder: FormBuilder;
ngOnInit() {
    this.complexForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        questionTypeDropDown: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
}
```

Then you can use valid property of FormGroup.

```
<button [disabled]="!complexForm.valid">Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you've defined the actual dropdown as the component.

If you're using reactive forms , you should be able to easily add Required validator to the control that you're creating like this :

```
 let myControl = new FormControl(null , Validators,required);
```

This would make the dropdown to be required.

If you're using template driven forms , you can still have this , you just need to set the `required=true` attribute to the element .

There are lots of other ways too.

Like , you can create a directive that can add the required field to the control , which I guess Angular2 already doing it anyway.

Comment: I am using template driven forms. You reckon I should have somethign like this: 
 <my-custom-dropdown ... required="true"></my-custom-dropdown>

Comment: Nope , it should be in the actual form element , like : <input required=true>

Comment: Can you provide an example?